# Jquery Stops c#button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp button when clicked upon loads up a popup in css using jquery. This works fine but its not triggering the c# on click event. I have a asp chart and when the pop up loads I want the chart enlarged in the popup window.

**Asp Button**

`<asp:Button ID="lbtnPaging" Runat="server" CustomParameter="Value1" onClick="lbtnPage_Click"   class="topopup" Text="Enlarge"  ></asp:Button>`

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$(".topopup").click(function () {

    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup
    }, 500); // .5 second
    return false;

});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function () {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function () {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});



/************** start: functions. **************/

function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();

}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
}



var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() {
    if (popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1


    }

}

function disablePopup() {
    if (popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
});    // jQuery End
```

C# Code

```
protected void lbtnPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

Comment: On the jquery you are returning false, and this stops the event from firing.

Comment: Sam is correct, returning false in javascript will stop its propagation to execute Click event.

Comment: Thanks Sam. So by not returning false has now worked but the popup which is created just disappears straight away.. ?

Comment: Click event cause to the page refresh due to which your pop up is being disappeared ..

Comment: can you please elaborate what you want to do exactly

Comment: ok. so i have a chart with a button. CLick on the button a popup appears.. with the same chart in the popup. How would i stop this page refresh.

Comment: use ajax webmethods, you can run a static method in code behind instead of the button event which will refresh the page, here is a tutorial : http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I wouldn't be able to access the chart controls on the page then would I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify jQuery event into

```
$(".topopup").click(function () {

    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function () { // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup
    }, 500); // .5 second
   // return false;    
});
```

`return false` Stops button default behavior. If you want to use return statement `return true` for calling server side Event